# NSMapTable "Generic parameter 'KeyType' could not be inferred"

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swift3

The following line is giving me the compiler error "generic parameter 'KeyType' could not be inferred":

```
fileprivate var delegatesMap = NSMapTable.strongToWeakObjects()
```

I tried being more explicit by saying:

```
fileprivate var delegatesMap:MapTable<Key,Value> = NSMapTable.strongToWeakObjects()
```

But I then Xcode doesn't recognize "Key"

How do I go about fixing this?

EDIT: I would like my Key to be of type String, and my Value to be of type MenuActionDelegate(class protocol)

Comment: No only Swift, but also I, do not see what KeyType you want to use. What types do you want to use as KeyType and ValueType for your `NSMapTable`?

Comment: I want to use string for key and a protocol "MenuActionDelegate" as the value

Comment: You' better include that sort of info into your question. I'll write a short answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write something like this:

```
fileprivate var delegatesMap = NSMapTable<NSString, MenuActionDelegate>.strongToWeakObjects()
```

The generic parameters `KeyType` and `ValueType` need to be `AnyObject`, so you cannot directly put `String` there, also you need some explicit casting `as NSString`.

And the value type `MenuActionDelegate` needs to an `@objc`-protocol.
Or else you may need to write something like this:

```
var delegatesMap = NSMapTable<NSString, AnyObject>.strongToWeakObjects()
```

And use it as:

```
let theDelegate = delegatesMap.object(forKey: "delegateName" as NSString) as! MenuActionDelegate
```

Comment: It's a class protocol, but I'm getting an error that says "MenuActionDelegate as a concrete type confronting to protocol 'AnyObject' is not supported"

Comment: @FaisalSyed, sorry, I have missed checking for class protocol. Can you change it an `@objc`-protocol?

Comment: I can't do that. How exactly would I add some explicit casting as NSString? I've tried several ways but haven't been able to do it properly

Comment: When I replace the MenuActionDelegate with AnyObject in the brackets, it wants me to cast all my String objects to NSString, and the second line doesn't compile

Comment: The second line gives the compiler error:"Cannot use instance member "delegatesMap" within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: That sort of usage, is not permitted even in Swift 2 -- using instance properties in an initial value of other instance property. If you want make `theDelegate` as an instance variable, you need to assign to it later somewhere in a instance method.